# Mapped drive in widows and delta updates

Tags: windows, network-share

Can someone help me confirm that a modification to a file in a mapped drive in windows would only update the delta and not copy the entire file across the network.

not sure how to identify how it works.

I'm trying to map a OneDrive folder to my server and drop some backups on to it, but the issue is one file could be 1 to 2 GB's and will be appended to periodically with the new changes. so after the initial copy will the files be uploaded in its entirety every time a small change happens.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will copy the entire file each time you make a change to it. What are the file types? Microsoft has made delta sync to SkyDrive (now OneDrive) available on Windows 8 with Office 2013 (for office docs).

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdedit/skydrive-delta-updates/c7f87609-39d4-458f-a141-f34d1217ffcc?tab=question&status=AllReplies&status=AllReplies

But outside of that, pretty sure you are stuck with uploading the entire file each time.